# Regular expression in java to replace string as mentioned below

Tags: java, regex, replace

```
<#if ${x} == 'abc' > ${add} <#else if ${y} == 'dfg' > bef </#if>
```

Here I want to remove all `${` and `}` which are inside `<` and `>` . , how can I do it in java?
expected output should be

```
 <#if x == 'abc' > ${add} <#else if y == 'dfg' > bef </#if>
```

Comment: Did you try something ?

Comment: No i was thinking of using split and then some kind of appending the processd strings....but in that case even ${add} will get changed which i dont want

Comment: So i m trying but not able to figure out whats need to be done..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
String str = "<#if ${x} == 'abc' > ${add} <#else if ${y} == 'dfg' > bef </#if>";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(<#.+?)\\$\\{(.+?)\\}(.+?>)", "$1$2$3"));
```

Yields:

```
<#if x == 'abc' > ${add} <#else if y == 'dfg' > bef </#if>
```

Regex Explanation available [here](http://regex101.com/r/tG7uJ3).

EDIT:
I have made some more amendments and also how I assume the `else` would be implemented. The code should do the trick:

```
String str = "<#if ${x} || ${z} > ${add} <#else if ${y} == 'dfg' && ${x} == 'abx'> bef <#else if ${y} == 'dfg' > sdadas <#else> ${foo}</#if>";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(?<=(?!<#else>)<#|\\|\\||&&)(.+?)\\$\\{(.+?)\\}", "$1$2"));
```

Given this:

```
<#if ${x} || ${z} > ${add} <#else if ${y} == 'dfg' && ${x} == 'abx'> bef <#else if ${y} == 'dfg' > sdadas <#else> ${foo}</#if>
```

Yields:

```
<#if x || z > ${add} <#else if y == 'dfg' && x == 'abx'> bef <#else if y == 'dfg' > sdadas <#else> ${foo}</#if>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..that worked.. but what if we have a expression like this <#if ${x} || ${z}  > ${add} <#else if ${y} == 'dfg' > bef <#else if ${y} == 'dfg' > sdadas </#if> where we have two ${} inside single < >.Then its not working

Comment: we can have n number of ${} inside any < > .So we have to replace all..can u pls tel solution for that

Comment: and we can have any number of if else statements too.

Comment: @user3678399: And how do you define `else`? Or you do not have any of those?

Comment: There can be or canot be any else..that depends..its not neccesory to have else part

Comment: Yeah Thanks a ton.Its working all fine with every condition now.i was struggling with this for so long..cheers :) .